# How to change the original filesystem (Squash FS) of Airties modem (model NO: Air5021)?

Tags: filesystems

I've been working on it since two weeks but still got no solution. I want to change the filesystem of an airties modem. I want to mount OpenWrt on it, so, via that way I want to make the whole system writable. Can you please redirect me to the solution?

Comment: You do know that SquashFS is a read-only file system?

Comment: Yep I know that. So, I tried to mount the firmware on my PC modify it and then put it back to the modem. But the thing is that I'm lack of .cue file so I couldn't do that either. I am now workin' on it(Firmware Modification Kit). BTW Do you know about trx headers? And how to change them? I want to do some changes to Firmware Modification Kit source to enable it to "unzip" any other file type rather than trx.